# How do I get the total views for a Facebook pagepost via the Graph API v2.7?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have been using the Facebook Graph API Explorer Version 2.7 to attempt getting the post_unique_impressions value for a Facebook Pagepost (i.e. the total number of unique views for a page post). Here is what I have tried:

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{page_id}_{post_id}/insights/post_impressions_unique?access_token={token}"
```

Response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{page_id}_{post_id}/insights/post_impressions?access_token={access_token}&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1473462734&until=1473721934",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{page_id}_{post_id}/insights/post_impressions?access_token={access_token}&debug=all&format=json&method=get&pretty=0&suppress_http_code=1&since=1473981134&until=1474240334"
  }
}
```

The `data` in the response is just an empty array, I would expect to either see a view count or to see some kind of error message. What do I need to do to get the unique impressions for a page post?

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights

Comment: What kind of access token did you use, and what permissions does it have?

Comment: It is a page access token. I found the problem, see my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution. Facebook Insights requires that your page have 30+ likes in order to generate insight data. I was using a throwaway Facebook page with no likes, so no Insights data was being generated. It's a little confusing since there's no error message in the API response, just an empty array of data.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights